# How can I contact moderator?

Tags: support, moderators

How can I contact moderator personally.

I want to tell him personally because I have doubt on couple of people, and I think they are playing upvote - upvote .

So I want moderator attention on those users

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do if peoples are working in a group, just to increase there profile reputation?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/what-to-do-if-peoples-are-working-in-a-group-just-to-increase-there-profile-rep)

Comment: @sv3n  I asked this question first, so you can mark that question as duplicate not old one

Comment: Just forgot to delete comment. I've retracted the flag. (It was just because other question was more detailed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just flag one of the posts of the  one of those "couple of people" and explain what the problem is, and what you suspect.

Comment: I raised the flag, please check it