# What to do if peoples are working in a group, just to increase there profile reputation?

Tags: discussion, voting, fraud-voting

I have just seen on the **MSE** that some peoples are working in a group for just **increasing** their **profile reputation**.

For example like **person-1** asks a question & within 20-30 minutes **person-2** gives his/her answer on that question & **person-1** do **upvote & accepts** the answer of **person-2**. We can't get it in just one time but If we properly monitor then we will see that if **person-1** has asked 4-5 questions on MSE then all his/hers questions are answered by **person-2** & **person-1** has always accepted his/hers answer.

This can be also neglected but when we see in the comments that **person-2** automatically get this thought into his/her mind that the **person-1** who have asked this question is using an extension or not.

We can neglect it in this sense that directly or indirectly by doing this they are providing something to the community but my question is.

Is it **fair** to the other **members** who are actually **working** in a fair manner for this **community** & **sharing** their **knowledge** here to help others?

Comment: https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/how-can-i-contact-moderator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For such cases All you can do is flag that answer/question as **in need of moderator intervention** and add what you feels wrong about that in description. Moderators will take the appropriate action.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it **fair** to the other **members** who are actually **working** in a fair manner for this **community** & **sharing** their **knowledge** here to help others?

Fraud voting is one of the baddest things for the community. It's doesnt hurts anybody directly, but for *community* itself it's just bad.

Some poeple spend a lot of time to give detailed answers (to serious) questions to get just a few ups. And others ...

You **should** flag this for moderator action, provide some details as above and you can be sure this will be investigated.

Comment: Downvoting questions may affect the response of a question

Answer (score 3):

> Is it fair to the other members who are actually working in a fair manner for this community & sharing their knowledge here to help others?

Your last question is interesting That's why I want to tell my opinion.

If you have discovered something new then ask question and answer your own question(after 2 hrs)

If this is the scenario then this way sharing knowledge is good but if this activity done by 2 people where one ask question and other answers then  **This is a Fraud voting Scenario**